# Storing Json parsed in Android using GSON

Tags: android, json, api, rest, gson

I'm very new to Android and I'm currently working on Android app that will parse JSON from a Restful API and display some of the data in a list view. I've looked into using GSON for parsing as the JSON was quite complex. Now my main problem is figuring out how to store the data somewhere so the app doesn't need to reload itself every time the activity is clicked on. I've looked at few questions here but they all seem to point to JSON only not GSON. Could anyone recommend an efficient way of doing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to store the data permanent it's the best way to insert your deserialized objects into a sqlite database or store them local to the disk as a file.

if your intention is to load the data for each startup, it's easier. just put your object into a public static object. so you can check if the object is not null or not. if it's null you have to load the data. 
another opportunity is using the SharedPreferences.

Comment: I think the second option you described above makes a lot of sense. However i forgot to mention that the data from the API changes daily and it's a large set of objects i'm working with. So the app needs to make requests to the API again if the day has changed. Would the second option you advised still be applicable in this case?

Comment: Yes you can use it. :) 
But it would be much better if you could check explicit if the local data is different from the server version. Maybe the API gives you a last modified timestamp or a versionnumber. You could save the value local and decide on this value if you need to update or not.

Comment: @qdor I just checked the JSON data and it does come with a timestamp  field. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: No problem. ;) you can rate my answer with a click on arrow up ;)

Comment: @qdor i'm very new to the site, not enough rep yet :/